# How to execute two Oracle stored procedure from a SQL Server 2008 R2 stored procedure using linked server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, stored-procedures

I'm trying to execute two oracle store procedure from SQL Server procedure using linked server.

Below is the syntax used:

```
EXECUTE('BEGIN ORAPROC1; END;')at [LinkedServerName] 
EXECUTE('BEGIN ORAPROC2; END;')at [LinkedServerName] 
RETURN @errCode;

HANDLE_ERROR:
  PRINT 'Error: ' + CAST(@errCode as varchar(100)) + ';  ' + @errMSG;
  RAISERROR (@errMSG, 16, 1)
  RETURN @errCode  

END
```

But only `ORAPROC1` is executing where as `ORAPROC2` is not.

I have added both execute statement before the SQL Server procedure error handling.

Is there something I'm missing in the syntax? Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative you can execute 2 Stored procedures inside a Begin - End syntax

```
EXECUTE('BEGIN ORAPROC1; ORAPROC2; END;')at [LinkedServerName]
```

Please let me know if it works for you.